# .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i want to create a clean url, as in, let say, i have a site www.mywebsite.com, i want, if anybody tries http://www.mywebsite.com/something, he should get redirected to  www.mywebsite.com,

so any thing that is typed ahead of mywebsite.com/  they should get redirected to www.mywebsite.com

how can i do this in .htaccess, kindly help.

Comment: Are you wanting only if the "something" doesn't exist to redirect, or are you planning to have no sub-content?

Comment: no no, i want like,  if you try to access http://www.mywebsite.com/anything, it should go to http://www.mywebsite.com

there should be nothing ahead of http://www.mywebsite.com/

the url should be clean, in the address bar it should only show http://www.mywebsite.com

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^/.+ / [L,R]
```

That will redirect everything to / as a permanent redirect. Look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html for more information on the flags you can add for transparency etc etc.

If you want this in `.htaccess` make sure you have the correct override directives in your `<VirtualHost >` config.

Comment: i have the following directives set in my virtual host:


<Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>



is this correct ?

Comment: Change `AllowOverride` to `All`, give that a try

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only redirect if there files and directories don't exists already, then this will work:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/.+ / [R,L]
```

If you never want to have sub-content accessible then remove the condition rules

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^/.+ / [R,L]
```

Comment: You need the `R` flag; otherwise, it's transparent to the user.