# How to redirect using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect all traffic like the following:

```
mydomain.com/a/b/c => www.mydomain.com/a/b/c
```

All url info should be reserved and only domain is modified.

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085920/htaccess-redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mudomain.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```