# Changing your url to do something else

Tags: php, apache, url

I don't know how to explain this, but I will try my best to explain it.

I am developing my website in php. So I have created an index.php file in Search folder

So if I have to search any word like 'good', it's address is

```
http://127.0.0.1/Website/search/?search=dh
```

Now if I try to access

```
http://127.0.0.1/Website/search/
```

I get an error on my page

```
Undefined index: search
```

because it is unable to find my $_GET["search"] variable which I am using to get the value of the input type.

Is there any way by which I can make this url

```
http://127.0.0.1/Website/search/something
```

be interpreted as

```
http://127.0.0.1/Website/search/?search=something
```

Comment: where is your PHP code? You should check whether `$_GET['search']` is set or not (via `isset()`) before accessing its value

Comment: okay thanks for this fix. But what about making your url interpret like another, any way to do it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: My question was basically the second one. Interpreting your url something else

Comment: It looks like you need to check out .htaccess if you want to remove the query string from your urls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085920/htaccess-redirect

Comment: Thanks I got it now. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Undefined index: search
```

"Because it is unable to find my $_GET["search"]" : Then check if the variable exists :

```
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    // use $_GET['search'];
}
```

For your second question, you can have an URL like "mysite.com/Website/search/something" using URL rewriting with htaccess.
Search these terms on SO or Google and you will find a lot of good tutorials.

Comment: Thanks..I think i can do it now :)

Answer (score 2):

**For first problem:** use `isset()` to check if `$_GET['search']` is defined before using it.

**For Second question:** use a `.htaccess` file with the rule

```
RewriteRule ^/search/(.+)$ /search/?search=$1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the:

```
Undefined index: search
```

error because you don't check if the variable exists.

To do this you can do a simple if statement like this one down below:

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
    // search index exists
}
```

For changing your URL you need to use URL rewriting, here is a good article about it: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

You should use rewrite rules in apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html
Than in Your script drop part of code reading "search" param and read $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , parse it to get through the "seach" part in URL and read whats after it.