# How to redirect a folder in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a website that has some pages have the same content in them.

Link 1 :

```
 http://abcxyz.com/abc/xyz/1233.html
```

Link 2 :

```
 http://abcxyz.com/xyz/1233.html
```

Two links above is one page. Now I want to redirect link 1 to link 2 with htaccess. But, there is a problem, abc in link 1 is not static. Some links are abc, some others are rpq , yklm...

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085920/htaccess-redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(xyz/.+?\.html)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks you for showing me that :D but the system says Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15.

Comment: @Johnny: To accept an answer you don't need 15 reps. You probably tried to upvote the answer. To accept you just need to click on **tick mark** which is just left of `share` link of my answer and it will turn green. Accepting an answer will give you 2 points as well.