# redirect url path from path to another using .htacess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect my url from one path to another

My website url : www.example.com/signup/generate/dashboard/index.php
but I want my website url as : www.example.com/login

how can I achieve this using .htaccess

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085920/htaccess-redirect)

Comment: "I want my website url as" - this doesn't sounds like a "redirect". It sounds like you actually want to change your URL structure? Have you tried anything? Do you have anything in your `.htaccess` file currently?

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` file in your root(normally called `public_html`) folder already? If you do its better if you post the contents of it so that we can provide a answer without conflicting with your already existing rules.